# How to add DOCTYPE via XQuery

Tags: xquery

I want to generate the following DOCTYPE with XQuery 3.1:

```
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
    <!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
]>
```

This is a special element , right? So I can't add them with normal element constructor.

Comment: It's not an element at all and as far as I can see from the XQuery standards processors don't have to explicitly support it. They have to appear after the XML declaration and before the root element so you may have to explicitly create a document node with the DOCTYPE declaration as a text node preceding the root element.

Comment: @chrisis why not just share your walk-around with us? the text node one

Comment: What is the XQuery engine?

Comment: @har07 newest BaseX

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of representing a DOCTYPE declaration in the XDM tree model, so this is tricky. There's also no equivalent of the XSLT workarounds such as disable-output-escaping or character maps, which provide ways of tweaking the way the tree is serialized to prevent the normal escaping of `<` as `&lt;`.

I think my preferred approach would be to post-process the serialized output of the query. For example, you could generate the DOCTYPE declaration (as a string) containing `«` and `»` in place of `<` and `>`, and then convert the chevrons to angle brackets in a post-processing phase using a text-based tool such as sed.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this might work.

```
    '<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
    <{!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
]>',
<rootnode>{let $fred := <bert></bert> return $fred}</rootnode>
```

Yes, that's valid XQuery which gives

```
 <!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
    <{!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
]>
<rootnode>
  <bert/>
</rootnode>
```

Not used this approach myself, I like my RDF as Turtle :).
There may well be a less ugly way.

Comment: The result of that query is likely to be serialized by escaping the angle brackets, e.g. `&lt;DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [ &lt;!ENTITY ....`

Comment: It is likely to be serialized and it will be serialized, this doesn't work